# How to handle the checkbox state with node and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, checkbox

I have an ejs file, which populates my checkboxes, like below. I do use an if statement to set the checkbox either as checked or unchecked...

```
<% taskList.forEach((task) => { %>
    <div class="task">
        <form class="task-content" action="/checked-box" method="post">
            <% if (task.solvedOn === false) { %>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= task._id %>" onchange="this.form.submit()" checked="<%= task.solvedOn %>">  
            <% } else { %> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= task._id %>" onchange="this.form.submit()" checked="<%= task.solvedOn %>">  
            <% } %> 
            <p> <%= task.name %> </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="taskListID" value="<%= list._id %>"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="taskListTitle" value="<%= list.title %>"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Now, whenever some clicks on the checkbox, node runs the following code to save the checkbox-state into a mongo DB.

```
app.post('/checked-box', (req, res) => {
  const taskID = req.body.checkbox;
  const listTitle = req.body.taskListTitle;
  const listID = req.body.taskListID;

  List.findOne(
    {_id: listID},
    {tasks: {
      $elemMatch: {
        _id: taskID 
      }
    }},
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(result.tasks);
      if (result) { 
        const checkboxStatus = result.tasks[0].solvedOn;
        console.log(checkboxStatus);
        if (checkboxStatus === false) {
          List.updateOne(
            {_id: listID, "tasks._id": taskID},
            {$set: {
              "tasks.$.solvedOn": true
            }}, 
            (err) => {
              if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/' + listTitle)
              }
            }
          )
        } else {
          List.updateOne(
            {_id: listID, "tasks._id": taskID},
            {$set: {
              "tasks.$.solvedOn": false
            }}, 
            (err) => {
              if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/' + listTitle)
              }
            }
          )
        }
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } 
  )
})
```

The problem is, that whenever I click on a checked Checkbox the task runs into an error:

undefined
node:events:504
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

But, if it is unchecked it works totally fine.

Does anyone know why? or how can I solve that problem?

Comment: This will be a difficult one to unpack, as it's not exactly reproducible in the code you provided.  I can tell you that your error message is referring to `checkboxStatus`.  `result.tasks` is undefined when you receive that message, so it can't access the `0` index of it.  I would look into your `findOne` query, or the `req.body` when checking the box.

Comment: Yes, maybe somehow. But I think the problem might be caused within the ejs file. Because when I try to log the task._id of a checked checkbox then this is already undefined. However, can anyone think of another way to handle the behavior of checkboxes and saving the state in mongodb?